# Half Bridge and Full Bridge Topologies

Tags: power-electronics

What is the main difference between half and full bridge topologies?

For instance, let's take the full and half bridge dual active bridge converter. I can understand that in the full bridge topologies, there are more switches. Thus we can use more complex and efficient control methods. Is there any main difference between the two topologies? When do we use the one topology instead of the other?

Full bridge
[image]

Half Bridge

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same thing as you mentioned. You mentioned aswell that a full bridge is more complicated in controlling.

You could outline their characteristics to see the differences. Based on that you could make a motivated choice for your application.

Half bridge: cheap, simple, low currents and big cap needed if you want small ripple.
Full bridge: more components so more expensive, more complicated and more efficient.

So to answer your question, you make a trade-off about what your application needs. If you want it to make it simple and cheap, because it is not that critical, you could go for a half bridge. If it is more critical then you mabye should implement a full bridge.